# Fprintf Error when writing to network mapped drive

Tags: go, printf

I have the following piece of code which creates an output file on a local drive and required to do the same on a network mapped drive let's call it [H:].
The file name (full path name) entered from command line as argument[1].

I am using Windows 10/Server 2016

```
// The following will create and append to the file when required.
    sourcefile, errf := os.OpenFile(os.Args[1], s.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND|os.O_RDWR, 0666)
    if erro != nil {
       panic(erro) 
     }
defer outfile.Close()
```

I use the following function to write a map into this file.

```
func map2Linpro(inp map[string][]string, outfile io.Writer) {
    for k, v := range inp {
        _, err := fmt.Fprintf(outfile, "%s %s=%s %s\n", v[0], k, v[1], v[2])
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error Writing to File: ", err)
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is working just fine if the output file is on the local Drive, but when using full path with the Mapped Drive letter, I received the following error:

```
Error:  write h://00_sc//dest01.txt: The parameter is incorrect.
```

I searched for any reason, but could not find one.
I would appreciate if someone help

The following is the Error I got after adding Panic(erro) after OpenFile.
Which proves that the error source is **fmt.Fprintf**

```
Error Writing to File:  write H:/00_sc/dest01.txt: The parameter is incorrect.
```

Thanks to all.

Comment: The path should be `h:\00_sc\dest01.txt` which in an interpreted literal looks like this: `"h:\\00_sc\\dest01.txt"`. If you use forward slashes, it must not be duplicated: `h:/00_sc/dest01.txt` (which may or may not work on Windows!

Comment: Why are you ignoring the error from `OpenFile`? Please don't do that. Otherwise what @icza said. Also note that Go supports "raw" string literals which are enclosed in backticks. You definitely need to read some basic introductory material on Go.

Comment: @icza Thanks for your reply, yes I have tried both \ and / and it causes the same error.

Comment: @kostix Thanks for your comment, I ignored the error in OpenFile, as it's a draft code.
I did not get what you mean by the introductory material, appreciate if you post a link to them.

Comment: here is some doc  https://golang.org/doc/code.html  and  https://golang.org/ref/spec  not to leave out  https://github.com/golang/go/wiki

Comment: You need to be really careful ignoring errors even in test or draft code @helhadad, as you may be ignoring errors which show up down the line (which seems to be what's happening here). Basically, don't ignore errors, even for quick tests, unless you're really really sure it will never fail (and even then it's probably a good habit to check).

Comment: Thank all for you comments and documents guide. The error here has nothing to do with the OpenFile as the code is running already when I use local file names.
The main issue which is not clear yet, is the Fprintf when the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

```
outfile, _ := os.OpenFile(os.Args[2], os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
```

should read

```
outfile, err := os.OpenFile(os.Args[2], os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)

if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}
```

rewrite those lines and the resulting error message should give a clue as to the cause

Comment: Thanks for reply, I added the error panic statement, however the received error is the same.
I believe the error is not from the OpenFile, as the file was created, but empty which means the issue with Fprintf while trying to write to the file!